# MySQL: Select For Update Mechanics

Tags: mysql, locking

I have a table where I stash hierarchical data. Data integrity is paramount.
I have a long-lasting transaction that spans multiple tables.
However, there is one table that is always read first despite the business logic use cases.
This table is called `tree_nodes`. Every tree belongs to the so-called holder. `holder_id` is the name of the column in the above-mentioned table.

The code is transactional.

Since my decisions are based on the contents of that table, I want to perform a gap locking query to block the other threads from reading the contents of the table for the duration of the transaction.

Here how it looks like:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM topic_nodes WHERE holder_id=? FOR UPDATE`

I am assuming that this will allow one thread to acquire a lock for the duration of the transaction while others will be patiently waiting for db to release the lock.

But this doesn't stop other threads from reading the data and making bad decisions based on what they see due to the data not being committed yet by the other transaction.

Am I doing smth wrong here? How can I solve this problem?

=======UPDATE=======

Here is the behavior that I experience, I see that all threads stop as one of them acquires the lock, and then after it finishes it seems like a latch being removed and the rest of them start hitting without acquiring a lock, I have appended the information below about the transactions when the lock is being held on the first thread.

```
---TRANSACTION 7492, ACTIVE 261 sec
1 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 10, OS thread handle 123145553260544, query id 1290 localhost 127.0.0.1 imochurad cleaning up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 7485, sees < 7485

---TRANSACTION 7491, ACTIVE 261 sec
1 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 11, OS thread handle 123145553575936, query id 1289 localhost 127.0.0.1 imochurad cleaning up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 7485, sees < 7485

---TRANSACTION 7490, ACTIVE 261 sec
1 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 17, OS thread handle 123145555468288, query id 1287 localhost 127.0.0.1 imochurad cleaning up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 7485, sees < 7485

---TRANSACTION 7489, ACTIVE 261 sec
1 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 15, OS thread handle 123145554837504, query id 1286 localhost 127.0.0.1 imochurad cleaning up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 7485, sees < 7485

---TRANSACTION 7488, ACTIVE 261 sec
1 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 18, OS thread handle 123145555783680, query id 1285 localhost 127.0.0.1 imochurad cleaning up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 7485, sees < 7485

---TRANSACTION 7487, ACTIVE 261 sec
1 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 12, OS thread handle 123145553891328, query id 1284 localhost 127.0.0.1 imochurad cleaning up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 7485, sees < 7485

---TRANSACTION 7486, ACTIVE 261 sec
1 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 16, OS thread handle 123145555152896, query id 1282 localhost 127.0.0.1 imochurad cleaning up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 7485, sees < 7485

---TRANSACTION 7485, ACTIVE 261 sec
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 9, OS thread handle 123145552945152, query id 1283 localhost 127.0.0.1 imochurad cleaning up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 7485, sees < 7485
```

Comment: The details are at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: @Barmar I have been to that URL gazillion times, I have updated the answer. I have also wanted to get some info on transactions I have attached how things look when the first thread is holding a lock... Any ideas why Transactions with higher ids do not see the changes made by the first transaction? What am I missing?

Comment: Pls do not ask the same question again.

Comment: I will remove the old one, this has more info

Comment: Just edit your old one.